# kubuntu 20.10 won't Start: xsession warning unable to write to /tmp

Tags: kernel, updates, kubuntu, login

My Kubuntu 20.10 won't let me log in. It says:

xsession: warning: unable to write to /tmp; x session may exit with an error

I think the system updated it's kernel before it happened.

What can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Disk was full after an update. Sorry